# How to you list of all pages in a .NET Razor Pages application?

Tags: razor-pages, .net-5, asp.net5

Is it possible to get a list of all pages in a .NET 5 Razor Pages application?

I have done it in MVC and Blazor before by getting a list of all types in the application and filtering it by their base types (`Controller` for MVC and `ComponentBase` for Blazor).

For Razor Pages you *could* do it by getting all types that implement `PageModel`, but that doesn't seem to work for pages that do not have a code-behind `.cshtml.cs` model file.

Comment: I can tell you one hack, you can get all the files from the `Pages` folder. by the way have you tried this `var temp = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                                 .ExportedTypes
                                 .Where(t => 
                                t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ComponentBase)));`

Comment: I would like to avoid hacks where possible. And yes the method you describe is exactly how I get a list of pages in Blazor (coupled with a check for the `RouteAttribute` that all the pages (.razor) with an `@page` directive get. I don't believe this is the case for Razor Pages (.cshtml) though, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to list all of the navigable pages, you can use the `EndpointDataSource` service. You can inject it into your PageModel constructor or directly into a Razor page. The following example returns the relative path of the page files, rooted in the Pages folder. The data is added to a Hashset to prevent duplications. There will be two endpoints for each Index file - one with a route template with `/Index` on the end and another with an empty string instead of `/Index`.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing
@inject EndpointDataSource EndpointsDataSource

@{
    HashSet<string> Pages = new HashSet<string>();
    foreach (var endpoint in EndpointsDataSource.Endpoints)
    {
        foreach(var metadata in endpoint.Metadata)
        {
            if(metadata is PageActionDescriptor)
            {
                Pages.Add(((PageActionDescriptor)metadata).RelativePath);
            }
        }
    }
}
<ul>
    @foreach(var p in Pages)
    {
        <li>@p</li>
    }
</ul>
```

If you want to get another property, documentation for the `PageActionDescriptor` type is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pageactiondescriptor

Also, if you wanted to get the route templates for each page, filter the metadata for types that are compatible with the  `PageRouteMetadata` type e.g.

```
if(metadata is PageRouteMetadata)
{
    Routes.Add(((PageRouteMetadata)metadata).PageRoute);
}
```