# How can i can get a list of razor pages in a razor pages app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to create a simple nav menu, that automatically populates with links to pages matching a specific query (such as subdirectory or name contains x etc..).

I can get the basic path of every indexed page using:

```
    HashSet<string> pages2 = new HashSet<string>();
    foreach (var endpoint in endpointDataSource.Endpoints)
    {
        foreach (var metadata in endpoint.Metadata)
        {
            if (metadata is PageRouteMetadata)
            {
                pages2.Add(((PageRouteMetadata)metadata).PageRoute);
            }
        }
    }
```

which I got from a similar question here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66972707/how-to-you-list-of-all-pages-in-a-net-razor-pages-application](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) 
But I don't fully understand what's happening here. What is in "endpointDataSource.Endpoints", where is it defined? And what is the "PageRouteMetadata" type etc... It also seems you can't use "endpointDataSource.Endpoints" outside of the .cshtml document, which seems odd.

Is there a better way to accomplish this? I assumed Razor Pages routing would inherently provide methods for this sort of thing, given it's touted as simplifying routing.

The docs are pretty unhelpful with circular referencing eg.
"DefaultEndpointDataSource Initializes a new instance of the DefaultEndpointDataSource class."
"DefaultEndpointDataSource Class Provides a collection of Endpoint instances."
"Endpoint Class Derived Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteEndpoint"

I'm sure that's incredibly useful to a .NET and MVC expert. But for me its just a bunch of terms that link to each other in a circle without ever explaining their purpose or use case.

I also tried asking on the .NET subreddit. But they pretty much just tried to sell me CMS services and claimed it can't be or shouldn't be done.

Edit: 27/1/23 What im trying to get working:

```
enter code here
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public readonly IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource> _endpointSources;
    public IndexModel(IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource> endpointDataSources)
    {
        _endpointSources = endpointDataSources;
    }

    public IEnumerable<RouteEndpoint> EndpointSources { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {

        EndpointSources = _endpointSources
                    .SelectMany(es => es.Endpoints)
                    .OfType<RouteEndpoint>();

        foreach(var endpointSource in EndpointSources) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(endpointSource);
            Debug.WriteLine(endpointSource.ToString());
            JSONTest.endpointStringTest.Add(endpointSource.DisplayName);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(JSONTest.endpointStringTest);
        Debug.WriteLine(JSONTest.endpointStringTest);
    }
}
```

But this results in a null reference. If i understand correctly, this is due to constructors being initialized and deleted before classes are? is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But i don't fully understand whats happening here. what is in
> "endpointDataSource.Endpoints", where is it defined?

Well,this kind of out of the box scenario, you might get less example on it as of now but it can be solved.  If you investigate you would seen `endpointDataSource.Endpoints` is type of  [`EndpointDataSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.endpointdatasource.endpoints?view=aspnetcore-7.0) which contains list of `Endpoints` where we can get information related to endpoint/page or route metadata.

[image]

> EndpointDataSource.Endpoints" outside of the .cshtml document, which
> seems odd.

[image]

As you can see `Endpoints` is a type of `IReadOnlyList` and it's parent class `EndpointDataSource` is a `abstruct` class so yes we cannot directly instantiate it but of course we can call it anywhere. Due to its `abstruction level` we need to inroduce constructor to invoke it.

> Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Yes, we do have the better in fact, eligant way to imvoke it to get the all page name therefore, its meta-data as well. Here is the complete demo for you.

**Asp.net core Razor Page For Getting All Containing Page Name:**

```
public class ListAllRazorPagesModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource> _endpointSources;
        public ListAllRazorPagesModel(IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource> endpointDataSources)
        {
            _endpointSources = endpointDataSources;
        }
       
        public IEnumerable<RouteEndpoint> EndpointSources { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {

            EndpointSources = _endpointSources
                        .SelectMany(es => es.Endpoints)
                        .OfType<RouteEndpoint>();
        }
    }
```

**Note:** I have injected `EndpointDataSource` using `ListAllRazorPagesModel` constructor to invoke `Endpoints` over it.

**View:**

```
@page
@model ListAllRazorPagesModel
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Display Name
            <th>URL
            <th>Route Pattern
           
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var pageName in @Model.EndpointSources)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@pageName.DisplayName?.TrimStart('/')</td>
                <td>@pageName</td>
                <td>@pageName.RoutePattern.RawText</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Im gonna try and implement this in it's own class/es so it can be called from any page (i don't really need to, but i wanna learn to).

Comment: Glad to assist you on this. Sure have a try.

Comment: Is it possible to do this in a method rather than constructor? or atleast pass the "EndpointSources" to another class/ variable to be used later? Because as far as i can tell this useless for anything other than displaying the endpoint data on this pages view and nothing else.

Comment: i added a new code example to the OP.

Comment: Could you please post a new question regarding your new concern so that it would nicer and this thread kept as unique.